# What does ClassName operator() declaration means?

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-overloading

I recently came across this class declaration

```
class Numeral_2 : public Numeral {
protected:
    friend Numeral;
    operator Numeral(); 
...
}
```

and couldn't figure out what does following code do

```
operator Numeral();
```

So what does it mean?

Comment: It's a user defined conversion operator.

Comment: In particular, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16615725/3002139).